# Is it possible for javascripts to have hrefs with IDs?

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to add an href containing an id to be inside runConfirm function? My aim is a pop-up to appear after I click accept and the accept button does the query from isset.

Here is my code for accepting.

```
$displaybody .= "<tr>
<td>" . $rows['lname'] . ", " . $rows['fname'] . "</td>
 <td>" . $rows['subject'] . "</td>
 <td>" . $rows['days'] . " " . $rows['rstime'] . " - " . $rows['retime'] . " 
</td>
   <td>" . $rows['note'] . "</td>
  <td>
<a class='runConfirm' data-id='" . $rows['rid'] . "'>Accept</a>                
<a href='home.php?decline=" . $rows['rid'] . "'>Decline</a>
</td>
</tr>"
```

And here is my function for the popup. (Updated)

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
        $(function(){
        $('.runConfirm').click(function(event){
          // get the id you want to act on
          var theId = $(this).data('rid');

          // ask user for confirmation
          alertify.confirm('Are you sure to accept this request?',

            // accepted
            function(){

              // go to the processing page
              window.location('/accept.php?rid=' + theId);
            },

            // declined
            function(){
              alertify.error('You clicked CANCEL');
          }).set('closable', false);

        });
        });
  </script>
```

Accept.php containing the process for accepting the booking.

```
    <?php
    include("server.php");
    session_start();

    if(isset($_GET['accept']))
    {
      $rid=$_GET['accept'];
            $query=$mysqli->query("SELECT qid FROM requests WHERE rid='".$rid."'");
                if($query->num_rows>0)
                {
                        while($rows=$query->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            $qid=$rows['qid'];
                        }
            }

     $query1=$mysqli->query("UPDATE qualified SET status='accepted' WHERE 
   qid='".$qid."' ");
     $query=$mysqli->query("UPDATE requests SET action='accepted' WHERE 
   rid='".$rid."'");

     header("Location:home.php");
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Is this possible? The button was unclickable

Comment: This happening bc page is redirected. Remove HREF attributte FROM a and give it ID with value. Then just get ID from a and implement it to js

Comment: Please see the new edit. Can you please tell me where to put it inside the js?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing PHP and Javascript in your second snippet. ```$_GET``` or ```header()``` for instance are PHP and will not be understood in a Javascript file.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to edit my new snippet.

Comment: What have you tried to answer that question? I don't get what you mean by "is it possible" - just print out the markup you expect and you're done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating the DOM, you could add a data attribute to the "Confirm" link which you could then access from your `runConfirm` click callback function.

Assuming that the id you want to use is in `$rows['rid']` that would give:
*(showing only changed parts for clarity)*

**Dom generation**

```php
$displaybody .= "<tr>
  <td>" . $rows['lname'] . ", " . $rows['fname'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $rows['subject'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $rows['days'] . " " . $rows['rstime'] . " - " . $rows['retime'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $rows['note'] . "</td>
  <td>
    <a class='runConfirm' data-id='" . $rows['rid'] . "'>Accept</a>                
    <a href='home.php?decline=" . $rows['rid'] . "'>Decline</a>
  </td>
</tr>"
```

**Popup handling** (updated)

```js
$('.runConfirm').click(function(event){
  // get the id you want to act on
  var theId = $(this).data('id');

  // ask user for confirmation
  alertify.confirm('Are you sure to accept this request?',

    // accepted
    function(){

      // go to the processing page
      window.location = '/accept.php?rid=' + theId;
    },

    // declined
    function(){
      alertify.error('You clicked CANCEL');
  }).set('closable', false);

});
```

And your third snippet would go in `accept.php`.

Your code will:

1. Render your table with row ids as data attribute
2. When clicking on "Accept", prompt the user for confirmation and send him to "accept.php" page.
3. Run the post-process code on the server which will eventually redirect the user to "home.php"

You can find out more on jQuery data in the doc: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Hello I have updated the codes as seen from above. I don't know where to put the update query. Please advise.

Comment: I've updated the answer. While this should do what you're trying to achieve, it's a bit cumbersome and the workflow could largely benefit from using AJAX.

Comment: Hello Moutah. Thanks for the reply. I've updated the snippets above with the accept.php(the-processing-page.php?rid=...etc.) The popup now appears but doesnt process. Can you please help me with this for the last time?

Comment: My bad, I had a mistake in the Javascript code, it sould be ```window.location = ...```. I've updated the answer, let me know if it's better now.

Comment: Thank you Moutah. I guess it's all in the accept.php now that has the problems. I don't know what to put in here. I put a snippet in there but I guess it's still not correct in receiving the id.

Comment: Indeed, the parameter name is not consistent. Window.location is passing ```rid=``` while accept.php is looking for ```accept``` in the ```$_GET``` object. I suggest you update the two ```$_GET['accept']``` to ```$_GET['rid']``` in ```accept.php```.

Comment: Moutah! Thank you so much for the help! It's now fixed :*

Comment: Glad to hear that :)